# How does trailing closure syntax works with PublicSubject<Void>.subscribe?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

```
let subject = PublishSubject<()>()
subject.subscribe {
  print("Why?") // onCompleted
}
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

This is the declaration of subscribe (from RxSwift)

```
public func subscribe(onNext: ((Self.E) -> Void)? = default, onError: ((Error) -> Void)? = default, onCompleted: (() -> Void)? = default, onDisposed: (() -> Void)? = default) -> Disposable
```

So, `Self.E` is also `Void` type. Why `onCompleted` is called instead of `onNext`? Their semantics are similar `(Void) -> Void`

I know, that i shouldn't write such code (as in example), i am just interested in this behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift, only if the last parameter is a closure can it be omitted and replaced with a trailing closure. What you think is `onCompleted` is actually `onDisposed`. You can see that in this code:

```
var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

let subject = Observable<Void>.create { observer -> Disposable in
    observer.onCompleted()
    return Disposables.create()
}
subject.subscribe(onNext: { _ in
    print("onNext")
}, onError: { (_) in
    print("onError")
}, onCompleted: {
    print("onCompleted")
}, onDisposed:  {
    print("onDisposed")
})
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

You will get the output:

```
onCompleted
onDisposed
```

Comment: Yes, thank u) Now i realised that it was kind of stupid question